# PhoneGap with Offline JQueryMobile

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, mobile

i followed this Guide to create my first PhoneGap app:
http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.de/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html
This works fine. Now, i want to use JQuery Mobile in this application.

I downloaded three files and put them into the same directory as my index.html.
The head of the index.html looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

doesnt work.
when i using the "online version" of jquery mobile, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

it works. But i want to make an offline app.
any idea?

Comment: Make sure that the path you are giving is correct if so, get the online version and keep that file inside your directory. But you still there are chances to miss the images which is used in the css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add jQuery reference before jQuery Mobile reference as JQM uses jQuery internally. In PhoneGap apps you should  not add references from CDN as it reduces the load time of the app drastically.

If you rearrange your local references like this, your code will work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```